# How to change the Icons (pac-icon) image based on type in google autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map autocomplete api for listing the locations. On predictions the results shown with the address details with the location icons. But I need to differentiate the location types based on the icons. (for example, if the location address is airport location means it should show the airport icon respectively). How to achieve this scenario..

```
<script>
    var map;
    var marker;
    var polygon;
    var bounds;
    var myLatLng = { lat: 51.507605, lng: -0.1300052 };
    var directionsService;
    var directionsDisplay
    window.onload = initMap;

    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: true
        });
        //map.setCenter(center);
        new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function (evt) {
            bounds = map.getBounds();
        });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center
        });
        polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            path: area,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FFd000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: '#FFd000',
            fillOpacity: 0.10
        });
        polygon.setMap(map);

        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    }

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        //alert($('#<%=tbPickupLoc.ClientID%>').val() + ' | ' + $('#<%=tbDropLoc.ClientID%>').val());

        directionsService.route({
            origin: $('#<%=tbPickupLoc.ClientID%>').val(),
            destination: $('#<%=tbDropLoc.ClientID%>').val(),
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @constructor
    */
    function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.originPlaceId = null;
        this.destinationPlaceId = null;
        this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
        var originInput = document.getElementById('<%=tbPickupLoc.ClientID %>');
        var destinationInput = document.getElementById('<%=tbDropLoc.ClientID %>');
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var options = {
            //rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE,
            componentRestrictions: { country: "GB" }
        };

        var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            originInput, options, { placeIdOnly: true });
        var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            destinationInput, options, { placeIdOnly: true });

        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');
    }

    AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function (autocomplete, mode) {
        var me = this;
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            marker.setMap(null);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            newBounds = bounds;
            if (!place.place_id) {
                window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
                return;
            }
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setMap(map);
            newBounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(newBounds);

            if (mode === 'ORIG') {
                me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
                $('#<%=hdnPickupLatLong.ClientID%>').val(place.geometry.location);
                if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)) {
                    $('#<%=hdnIsPickupOptArea.ClientID%>').val("true");
                }
                else {
                    $('#<%=hdnIsPickupOptArea.ClientID%>').val("false");
                }
            }
            else {
                me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
                $('#<%=hdnDropLatLong.ClientID%>').val(place.geometry.location);

                if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)) {
                    $('#<%=hdnIsDropOptArea.ClientID%>').val("true");
                }
                else {
                    $('#<%=hdnIsDropOptArea.ClientID%>').val("false");
                }
            }
            me.route();
        });
    };

    AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function () {
        $('#<%=hdnMiles.ClientID%>').val("0");
        $('#<%=hdnDuration.ClientID%>').val("0");
        $('#<%=lbMiles.ClientID%>').text("Distance is " + $('#<%=hdnMiles.ClientID%>').val() + " miles and Duration is " + $('#<%=hdnDuration.ClientID%>').val() + " mins");

        /* Place Service */
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        if (this.originPlaceId != null) {
            $('#<%=hdnOriginId.ClientID%>').val(this.originPlaceId);
            service.getDetails({
                placeId: this.originPlaceId
            }, function (place, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    $('#<%=hdnPickupAddr.ClientID%>').val(place.formatted_address);
                    var _typesArr = place.types;
                    var _type = _typesArr[0];
                    //alert(_type + "-" + place);

                    if (_type == "airport") {
                        $('#<%=hdnPickupType.ClientID%>').val("A");
                        $('#<%=hdnPickupAddr.ClientID%>').val("");
                    }
                    else if (_type == "lodging") {
                        $('#<%=hdnPickupType.ClientID%>').val("H");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        if (this.destinationPlaceId != null) {
            $('#<%=hdnDestId.ClientID%>').val(this.destinationPlaceId);

            service.getDetails({
                placeId: this.destinationPlaceId
            }, function (place, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    $('#<%=hdnDropAddr.ClientID%>').val(place.formatted_address);

                    var _typesArr = place.types;
                    var _type = _typesArr[0];

                    if (_type == "airport") {
                        $('#<%=hdnDropType.ClientID%>').val("A");
                        $('#<%=hdnDropAddr.ClientID%>').val("");
                    }
                    else if (_type == "lodging") {
                        $('#<%=hdnDropType.ClientID%>').val("H");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
            return;
        }

        var me = this;

        /* Direction Service */
        this.directionsService.route({
            origin: { 'placeId': this.originPlaceId },
            destination: { 'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId },
            travelMode: this.travelMode
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                var distanceinkm = distance / 1000;
                var distanceinmiles = (distanceinkm * 0.621371);
                distanceinmiles = distanceinmiles.toFixed(2);

                var duration = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
                var dvDistance = "";

                duration = parseFloat(duration / 60).toFixed(2);

                dvDistance += "Distance is " + $('#<%=hdnMiles.ClientID%>').val() + " miles and ";
                dvDistance += "Duration is " + $('#<%=hdnDuration.ClientID%>').val() + " mins";

            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    };

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5123443, -0.09098519999997734);
    var area = [
        { lat: 51.249669, lng: -0.142219 },
        { lat: 51.273731, lng: 0.146172 },
        { lat: 51.421264, lng: 0.261528 },
        { lat: 51.578564, lng: 0.310967 },
        { lat: 51.691076, lng: 0.126946 },
        { lat: 51.704695, lng: -0.169685 },
        { lat: 51.733621, lng: -0.257576 },
        { lat: 51.588804, lng: -0.534981 },
        { lat: 51.361279, lng: -0.548714 },
        { lat: 51.304649, lng: -0.488289 },
        { lat: 51.249669, lng: -0.142219 }
    ];
</script>
```

[Our Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loWTV.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTPQ3.png)

Comment: Post your code, we don't know what you are using and how. Please see how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi... I have added the code for your reference..

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Autocomplete of Maps JavaScript API doesn't allow to set custom icons for different types of predictions. There is a feature request for this in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66101726

Feel free to star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.

In the meantime if you would like to have custom icons you have to implement your own autocomplete widget using the `AutocompleteService` class of Maps JavaScript API.

You can see the idea in the following code snippet

```js
function initService() {
  var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }

    var items = {};
    var ap = [];
    var arrPlaces = [];

    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
      arrPlaces.push(prediction.place_id);
      items[prediction.place_id] = {
        icon_url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
        description: prediction.description
      };
      if (prediction.types.includes('transit_station')){
        ap.push(getPlaceTypes(prediction.place_id)); 
      }
    });
    
    Promise.all(ap).then( function(values) { 
      values.forEach(function(value){
        if (value.types.includes('bus_station')) {
          items[value.placeId].icon_url = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bus-71.png";
        } else {
          items[value.placeId].icon_url = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/train-71.png";
        }
      });
      arrPlaces.forEach(function(pId){
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var icon_url = items[pId].icon_url;
        var icon = document.createElement("IMG");
        icon.src = icon_url;
        icon.width = 24;
        icon.height = 24;
        li.appendChild(icon);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[pId].description));
        document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
      });
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({ input: 'gare montparnasse' }, displaySuggestions);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  function getPlaceTypes(placeId) {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        geocoder.geocode({placeId: placeId}, function(result, status){
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              resolve({
                placeId: placeId,
                types: result[0].types
              }); 
          } else {
              reject(status);
          }
        });
    });
    return p;
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select, #right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="right-panel">
  <p>Query suggestions for 'gare montparnasse':</p>
  <ul id="results"></ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&language=fr&libraries=places&callback=initService" async defer></script>
```

The complete sample is also available on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/dufizuq/edit?html,output

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can replace it with this CSS

```
.pac-icon {
    background-image: url('../img/geo-alt-fill.svg') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the google documentation to do it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete

```
.pac-container  {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  .pac-item {
    @include font-source-sans($font: 'Lato', $size: 13px, $colour: #a3a4ab, $weight : 300, $lh : 18px);
    margin: 0 -10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    .pac-matched {
      color: #191818;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    .pac-item-query {
      color: #6d6c6c;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    &:first-child {
      border: 0
    }
  }
}


.pac-icon {
  background: url('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white3.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px 6px 6px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pac-item-selected, .pac-item:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.04);
}
```

Comment: this doesnt answer the question, it's not about styling the icon, it's about changing the icon depending upon the type of place returned